# How to create google map markers and polyline after you have removed them?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a running tracking web app. When you press the start button it starts tracking you. The red marker is the start position and the blue marker tracks your current location and there is a polyline creating a path between the two points.

When I press the "stop" button it deletes the marker's and polyline which is what I want. But when I press the "start" button again after this I want it to just repeat what it did when you first originally press the start button. E.g Create a red marker at the start position and then a blue marker to track the users movements and also create a polyline between the two points.

Currently it is only creating the blue marker and nothing else. How do I fix this?

**[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNoqqq)**

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Runna - Track your run!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <header>
        <img src="imgs/logo-blue.png" />
    </header>
    <div id="map-container">
      <div id="map_canvas">Press start to begin</div>
    </div>
    <div class="show-controls"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></div>
    <section id="control-container">
        <div class="column left">

                <div id="left-wrapper">
                    <div class="left-top">
                       <ul>
                          <li><b>Distance</b></li>
                          <li class="distance-total"></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="left-bottom">
                        <ul>
                          <li><b>Duration</b></li>
                          <li><span id="stop-watch">00:00:00</span></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="column middle">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" class="arrow"><div><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div></a>
                      <a href="#" id="start"><div>START</div></a>
                      <a href="#" id="stop"><div>STOP</div></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
            <div id="right-wrapper">
                    <div class="right-top">
                       <ul>
                          <li><b>Speed</b></li>
                          <li class="calories-total"></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="right-bottom">
                        <ul>
                           <li><b>Share</b></li>
                              <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>

                              <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
               </div>

        </div>
    </section>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
// Global Variables ===========================================================================================

var watchID = null;
var geo;
var map;
var startMarker = []; // Red Marker
var endMarker = []; // Blue Marker
var geo_options = {
   enableHighAccuracy: true,
   maximumAge: 100000,
   timeout: 20000
};
var pathLineArray = new Array();
var mypath;
var lastLatLng = pathLineArray[pathLineArray.length - 1];

$(document).ready(function() {

   // Show and hide the bottom bar -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   var arrowButton = $('a.arrow');
   var controlContainer = $('#control-container');

   arrowButton.on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      controlContainer.fadeOut('fast');
      $('.show-controls').show();
      $('#map-container').css('height', '87vh');
   });

   $('.show-controls').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      controlContainer.fadeIn('fast');
      $('.show-controls').hide();
      $('#map-container').css('height', '65vh');
   });

// Stop watch script ===========================================================================================

   var   h2 = document.getElementById('stop-watch'),
         start = document.getElementById('start'),
         stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
         seconds = 0,
         minutes = 0,
         hours = 0,
         t;

   function add() {
      seconds++;
      if (seconds >= 60) {
         seconds = 0;
         minutes++;
         if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
         }
      }

      h2.innerHTML = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

      timer();
   }

   function timer() {
      t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
   }

   /* Start button */
   start.onclick = function() {
      timer();

   }

   // Resets the stop watch
   function resetTimer() {
      clearTimeout(t);
      h2.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
      seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
   }

// End of Stop watch script ===========================================================================================

   $('#start').click(startWatching);

   if (geo = getGeoLocation()) {
      // startWatching(); Only uncomment if you want the map to load straight away upon page load
   } else {
      alert('Geolocation is not supported');
   }

   $('#stop').click(function() {
      var stopQuestion = confirm("Are you sure you want to stop?");

      if (stopQuestion) { 
         stopWatching();
         mypath.setMap(null); // Deletes path/polyline that has been created
         startMarker.setMap(null); // Deletes the start red marker
         endMarker.setMap(null); // Deletes the end blue marker
         resetTimer();
         } else {
            return;
         }
   });
}); // Ready block finish here

function getGeoLocation() {
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
      return navigator.geolocation;
   } else {
      return "Undefined";
   }
}

function startWatching() {
   watchID = geo.watchPosition(show_coords, geo_error, geo_options);
   // watchID = geo.getCurrentPosition(show_coords, geo_error, geo_options);
}

function stopWatching() {
   if (watchID != null) {
      geo.clearWatch(watchID);
   }
}

function show_coords(position) {

   var speed = position.coords.speed;
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var lon = position.coords.longitude;
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
   var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(pathLineArray);
   var distanceInKM = distance / 1000; // Converts Meters To KM
   var distanceRounded = distanceInKM.toFixed(2); // Allows only two decimal points
   var speedInKPH = speed * 3.6; // Converts Meters per second (default value) to kilometers per hour

      // Updates the text with the latest distance figure
      $('.distance-total').text(distanceRounded + "KM");

      $('.calories-total').text(speedInKPH + " kph");

      if (map) {

         // Makes it so that it doesnt have to reload the map everytime, it just pans to the new position
         map.panTo(latlng);

      } else {
         var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         };

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

         mypath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: pathLineArray,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            map: map

         });

         startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
         });

      }
      // Push lat and long coords to this array
      pathLineArray.push(latlng);

      if (mypath) {
         mypath.setPath(pathLineArray);

      } else {
         mypath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: pathLineArray,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 4,
            map: map,
         });
      }

      if (endMarker && endMarker.setPosition) {
         endMarker.setPosition(latlng);
         endMarker.setMap(map);
      } else {
         endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
         });
      }

} // End of show_coords(position) function


function geo_error(error) {
   switch (error.code) {
      case error.TIMEOUT:
         alert("geolocation timeout");
         break;
      case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
         alert("Gelocation position unavailable");
         break;
      case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
         alert("Permission denied");
         break;
      default:
         alert('Unknown error');
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Nope there isn't. I believe I have solved the problem, just testing it atm. The way I think I have fixed it is I have set the `map` variable back to an empty variable in my `stop` click event.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue:

I needed to set my `map` variable back to an empty variable.

Code:

```
$('#stop').click(function() {
      var stopQuestion = confirm("Are you sure you want to stop?");

      if (stopQuestion) { 
         stopWatching();
         mypath.setMap(null); 
         startMarker.setMap(null);
         endMarker.setMap(null);
         map = ''; // Added this in to set it back to empty
         pathLineArray = [];
         resetTimer();
      }
});
```